# How to get the job status of gis.item.export or make it execute synchronously?

Tags: arcgis-rest-api, arcgis-python-api

I'm using the ArcGIS API for Python to export a feature service to a FGDB and then download it.
My problem is that the export function appears to be asynchronous even though I set `wait=True`.

The returned item from `gis.item.export()` has a jobid so this shouldn't be a problem if I could poll the service for job status but I don't see a URL to do this.

Without a synchronous export or a job status I am user `time.sleep(60)` to slow things down but that not exactly ideal

So how do I get my export to execute synchronously, or how do I query the job status?

```
def Get_AGOL_Data_All2(itemID):
    """
    PARAMETERS:
      itemID (str) = Ther Portal itemID of the feature service to download.

    RETURNS:
      None

    FUNCTION:
      Uses the arcgis api for python library to connect to Portal and copy a feature service to a 
      FGDB. Portal returns a zipped file which then has to be unzipped and the contents moved to the staging location

    NOTE:

    """

    print ('Starting Get_AGOL_Data_All()')
    # #anon_gis = GIS()
    mygis = GIS(username="userid",password="****")

    service = mygis.content.get(itemID)
    itemDesc = service.export(title="DamageReports", export_format= 'File Geodatabase', parameters=None, wait='True')
    time.sleep(60)
    fgdb = mygis.content.get(itemDesc['exportItemId'])


    fgdb.download(r"D:\temp")
    
    with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join( r"D:\temp" , fgdb.name),'r') as zip_tar:
        zip_tar.extractall(r"D:\temp")
    print ('Finished Get_AGOL_Data_All()')
    arcpy.Rename_management(os.path.join(r"D:\temp", zip_tar.filelist[0].filename.split("/")[0]),"DamageReports.gdb")

    return
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a typo on my part. I had quotations around the wait parameter value. Changing `wait='True'` to `wait=True` worked perfectly.